# Find basis of $V$ and $W$ containing the basis of $V ∩ W$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Define two vector subspace of $\Bbb R^5$ :

$$V = \{(v, w, x, y, z) \in \Bbb R^5 : v + x − 3y + z = 0\}$$

$$W = \{(v, w, x, y, z) \in \Bbb R^5 : w − x − z = 0; v = y\}.$$

Find basis of $V$ and $W$ containing the basis of $V ∩ W$.

Each basis of $V$ (Dim: $4$) and $W$ (Dim:$3$) can be found as well as basis for $V ∩ W$ (Dim : $2$). But how to find basis of $V$ (and $W$) which contains all basis elements of  $V ∩ W$?

Comment: Go backwards: out of a basis of $V\cap W$ construct a basis for $V$ and one for $W$, then these will for sure satisfy the requests

Comment: Just find a basis for the intersection first (solve the system of all equations). Then complete by linearly independent vectors in $V$ respectively in $W$ (drop the other equations and find what new solutions to the weaker system appear).

Comment: V∩W basis gives { (1,2,2,1,0), (0,0,-1,0,1) } while basis V = {(-1, 0,1,0,0), (3,0,0,1,0), (-1,0,0,0,1), (0,1,0,0,0) }.

Comment: A sentence beginning with an imperative should not have a question mark in its end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the corresponding linear system to find the intersection:

$$\begin{cases}&I\;&v+x-3y+z=0\\{}\\&II\;&w-x-z=0\\{}\\&III\;&v=y\end{cases}\;\;\implies I\;v+x-3v+z=0\implies 2v=x+z\stackrel{II}=w$$

Thus, we have two free variables $\;x,z\;$, from which all others get uniquely determined, and thus $\;\dim V\cap W=2\;$ , for example

$$V\cap W=\left\{\,(x+z,\,2x+2z,\,2x,\,x+z,\,2z)\in\Bbb R^5\,\right\}=\text{Span}\,\left\{\,(1,2,2,1,0)\;,\;\;(,1,2,0,1,2)\,\right\}$$

Now complete the above to (1) a basis of $\;W\;$ , and then (2) to a basis of $\;V\;$ .

Comment: basis V = {(-1, 0,1,0,0), (3,0,0,1,0), (-1,0,0,0,1), (0,1,0,0,0) }.                  So is Basis V = { (1,2,2,1,0),(,1,2,0,1,2), (-1, 0,1,0,0), (3,0,0,1,0), (-1,0,0,0,1), (0,1,0,0,0) }  ??

Comment: @Recoder What? I'm not sure I understand how those two "basis"
 of the same space $\;V\;$  have a different number of elements, and in the second case how that "basis" can have more elements than the dimension of the whole space...!

Comment: I meant write the set as  { (1,2,2,1,0),(,1,2,0,1,2), (-1, 0,1,0,0), (3,0,0,1,0), (-1,0,0,0,1), (0,1,0,0,0) } and then remove the linearly dependent ones so as to get dim 4. is that correct?

Comment: @Recoder I've no idea: do all those vectors belong to $\;V\;$ ? And if they do, do they generate it? If the answer to both question is *yes* then you indeed can take a basis from all those vectors...but I don't understand why you do that: the two vectors given in my answer are lin. indep. **and in** $\;V\;$ , so you only need to complete these two to four vectors in $\;V\;$ lin. ind.

Comment: I need to find basis of V that has {(1,2,2,1,0), (1,2,0,1,2)} in it plus two other elements.

Comment: so what are the other two elements in basis of V?

Comment: @R You find them! There are infinite possibilities to choose two vectors in $\;V\;$ that with the already two given ones will give a basis. Just choose elements that fit the condition defining elements in $\;V\;$ , put them together with the two already given in a matrix, reduce the matrix and...voila.

Comment: is it a basis of V {(1,2,2,1,0),(,1,2,0,1,2), (-1, 0,1,0,0), (3,0,0,1,0)} ? The first two being from  V∩W and other being any two from basis (speaking in general) V= {(-1, 0,1,0,0), (3,0,0,1,0), (-1,0,0,0,1), (0,1,0,0,0) }

Comment: @Recoder Don't you know how to check whether some vectors (of the sam dimension, of course) are lin. indep. or not? With matrices? This is basic stuff...Otherwise I've no idea how you're supposed to solve this question.